# Always Encrypted with Asp.net Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, always-encrypted

We are trying to use Always Encrypted feature of Sql 2016 with Asp.net Identity 2.0.  We have a requirement to encrypt customer's data when we store it to AspNetUsers table.  This is to follow GDPR compliance.  We have set Always Encrpted on PhoneNumber and Email columns.  We are able to encrypt phone number but the register method in Account Controller fails when we try to encrypt email column.  We get the following exception when we try to register:

> System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()",
>       "InnerException": {
>           "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>           "ExceptionMessage": "Operand type clash: nvarchar(256) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'StoreIdentityEF6AE') collation_name = 'Latin1_General_BIN2' is incompatible with varchar",
>           "ExceptionType": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",

Has anyone encountered this issue and resolved successfully?  Looking for some suggestions to encrypt customer data  with Asp.net Identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have struggled with this question as well and think I've found the solution.

ASP.NET Identity uses the UserStore: [see implementation here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/UserStore.cs)

In that UserStore some methods use the ToUpper method.
Your Email column is encrypted and therefor the ToUpper method can't work. It can't create a query that contains a SQL ToUpper logic.

What we have do is build our custom implementation of the IUserStore and remove to ToUpper from the queries on EmailAddress.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Terry.  We are using code based encryption as there were other logistic challenges in using database level encryption.  But for sure, I will try your suggestion of custom IUserStore next time.